# Accessing WinRT .NET Framework types and methods from embedded Lua?

Tags: .net, windows, lua, com, luajit

I use an application ([MUSHclient](https://www.aardwolf.com/play/downloadmc.htm)) which contains Lua scripting capability, provided by the [LuaJIT](https://luajit.org/) engine. I'm aware of 3 different ways in which Lua inside MUSHclient can call out to external code:

1. Foreign Function Interface via LuaJIT's "ffi" - this allows accessing C libraries
2. COM Objects via "luacom" - this allows accessing Microsoft's Component Object Model
3. Windows executables via `os.execute` or `utils.shellexecute`

I want to be able to create Windows toast notifications from my MUSHclient Lua scripts, and it seems the easiest way to do that is by using the `CreateToastNotifier` method of the `Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager` WinRT .NET Framework object type.

I don't have the access/capability to modify the MUSHclient code itself, so I would need to be able to do this from Lua script code that can run inside MUSHclient.

I currently achieve this using method 3 described above, calling out to an external utility [toast](https://github.com/go-toast/toast), but this method is clunky, and I wondered if there's any way to get from FFI or COM Objects to .NET Framework objects and methods?

Comment: You can create a COM object with .NET Framework (or .NET Core/5+) and call that from LUA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-dotnet-components-to-com That COM object can then call any Windows API. (PS: ToastNotificationManager  is not a .NET object, it's a WinRT object that can be bound to .NET)

Comment: BTW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74963238/20468470) is an example of creating simple notifications (not toast) using LuaJIT

Comment: @ESkri I did see that. However as you point out, it doesn't create a toast notification. Also, the notifications it does create are much more limited in their form and function than true Windows 10/11 toast notifications.